# Conda always shows '[y/N]' then nothing happen

Tags: conda

OS: MacOS X 10.15.1

I met a problem that my Conda always shows [y/N] whatever command I input:

such as:

```
$ conda list
[y/N]:y
```

```
$ conda info
[y/N]:y
```

And after I input 'y', nothing happened and the process ends.

what I have tried:
Reinstall Anaconda:

```
$ bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.10-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
```

then after plenty of 'Extracting' it shows again.

```
(Extracting...)
[y/N]: %
```

Again, it ends.

Comment: Try running some commands with verbose flag (`-vv` or `-vvv`) and add what happens to your question. Hopefully, you can pinpoint what point in the Conda code is leading to this prompt.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I solved this problem with the verbose information. It told me that the reason is the profile '~/.condarc'

Comment: This will be a dumb solution, but it worked for me.  I had to change my directory (literally 'cd ..') and all the conda commands started working.  I have no idea why this works.

Comment: What shell? `zsh` or `bash`?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is some setting in '~/.condarc'. After I delete it, the problem solved, and Conda works well.

```
$ rm ~/.condarc
```

Answer (score 1):

Another reason this can happen is if you have a conda environment already active that might be 'broken' in some way. To fix it:

```
conda deactivate
```

Then try your conda command again.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue and i fixed by updating anaconda `sudo conda update anaconda`  command

Comment: End users should generally not have Conda installed with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue which started after I added some proxy settings to the .condarc file. Solved it by removing the { } at the beginning and the end of the file.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, it was due to OOM (out of memory) on the system.

Comment: welcome to so, it is better write this answer in the comment