# conda stuck on [y/N] prompt

Tags: python, conda

My problem is similar to this this post

[Conda always shows '[y/N]' then nothing happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59301994/conda-always-shows-y-n-then-nothing-happen)

My conda is stuck. When I try to do anything, it shows a prompt for [y/N]. Then nothing happens.

```
$ conda env list
[y/N]:
```

Typing in 'Y' doesn't do anything.

The weird thing is that even if I type in a bogus conda command, I still get the same behavior.

```
$ conda abc
[y/N]:
```

Also, passing in --yes results in the same behavior.

Here is my ~.condarc

```
channels:
  - remote-repos-conda
  - remote-repos-conda-forge
  - TEAM_CONDA_LIB
  - defaults
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/mosek

channel_alias: http://TEAM_ARTIFACTORY:8081/artifactory/api/conda/
channel_priority: True
always_yes: True
allow_other_channels: False
show_channel_urls: True
ssl_verify: False
auto_update_conda: False
```

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Is `channels:` really indented like that? or is that just a formatting error here? It is crucial this is correctly formatted because YAML is sensitive to whitespace. Consider also adding outputs from `which conda` and `type conda` to the question body. Maybe check your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc`) to make sure nothing weird is going on with the `# >>> conda initialize` section.

Comment: I had a problem recently manifesting in the same behavior. For me the shebang line in the conda script was pointing to a non-existing python executable. Fixing the shebang line to an existing python interpreter also fixed the issue for me. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my opinion, Anaconda has been more and more unreliable lately. I get issues like this all the time.